# gitlab_ci redirects to gitlab

Tags: nginx, gitlab

i just installed  [gitlab_ci](http://gitlab.org/gitlab-ci/) with nginx using this [installation guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci/blob/master/doc/installation.md) (followed it step-by-step and all worked fine).

I have a gitlab installation running in the same machine ( gitlab.loc ).
The Domain I wnat to use for gitlab_ci is "gitlab-ci.loc".

I'm using the provided configuration for nginx (just changed server_name to gitlab-ci.loc).

**The Problem:** When I try to open gitlab-ci.loc in my Browser it delivers me the gitlab page, like if i had called gitlab.loc instead of gitlab-ci.loc.
The Browser address schows gitlab-ci.loc, so i think i done something wrog in nginx configuration.

nginx conf for gitlab_ci

```
# GITLAB CI
# Maintainer: @randx
# App Version: 2.0

upstream gitlab_ci {
  server unix:/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/tmp/sockets/gitlab-ci.socket;
}

server {
  listen *:80 default_server;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80;
  server_name gitlab-ci.loc;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  root /home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/public;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_ci_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_ci_error.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab_ci;
  }

  location @gitlab_ci {
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab_ci;
  }

  # adjust this to match the largest build log your runners might submit,
  # set to 0 to disable limit
  client_max_body_size 10m;
}
```

nginx conf for gitlab
    # GITLAB
    # Maintainer: @randx
    # App Version: 5.0

```
upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
  listen *:80 default_server;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most cases *:80 is a good idea
  server_name gitlab.loc;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  server_tokens off;     # don't show the version number, a security best practice
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;

  # Set value of client_max_body_size to at least the value of git.max_size in     gitlab.yml
  client_max_body_size 5m;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
}
```

config/application.yml

```
defaults: &defaults
  allowed_gitlab_urls: 
    - 'https://dev.gitlab.org/'
    - 'https://staging.gitlab.org/'

  ## Gitlab CI settings  
  gitlab_ci:
    ## Web server settings
    host: gitlab-ci.loc
    port: 80
    https: false

    ## Email settings
    # Email address used in the "From" field in mails sent by GitLab-CI
    email_from: gitlab-ci@localhost

    # Email address of your support contact (default: same as email_from)
    support_email: support@localhost

    # Send emails for all failing builds
    # all_broken_builds: true

    # Add committer to recipients list
    # add_committer: true

  gravatar:
    enabled: true
    plain_url: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/%{hash}?s=%{size}&d=mm"
    ssl_url:   "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/%{hash}?s=%{size}&d=mm"


development:
  <<: *defaults
  neat_setting: 800

test:
  <<: *defaults
  allowed_gitlab_urls: 
    - 'http://demo.gitlab.com/'

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two servers defined as `default_server`. The second one will not load, and the one defined first will take over all requests. Change one of the `listen` lines to

```
listen *:80;
```

and reload Nginx.